# Java/Android how to get JSON from a html response?

Tags: java, android, json, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm getting an html response from HttpGet,the response is like following:

```
<div class="noti-contents">
    <button class="accept-invitation gui-button" data-invite="pi:103158:18:60:114779" data-invite-details='{"f":"103158","p":18,"api":false,"pid":60,"t":114779,"sub":"p10315857a3f8","u":{"id":"103158","name":"xxxxxx","profile_image":"{1}","status":"1"}}'><span>Accept</span></button>
</div>
```

and all the above code are stored in a string variable 'response'; but now in my app i only need the JSON part of the html:

```
{"f":"103158","p":18,"api":false,"pid":60,"t":114779,"sub":"p10315857a3f8","u":{"id":"103158","name":"xxxxxx","profile_image":"{1}","status":"1"}}
```

so how should I parse this string to get the only the above part?

Comment: use jsoup html parser and get the json

Comment: @Raghunandan but i think jsoup needs url of the page to get the html of the page, the html code in this question are sent to me as a response, I don't have the url of this html, how should I use jsoup to parse this?

Comment: you can parse the string response

Comment: what is u the response that you get a string??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the docs

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html

You can use Jsoup to parse html

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("html string");  
Elements elements = doc.select("button");
Log.i("..........",""+elements.attr("data-invite-details"));
```

Log

```
08-15 19:16:42.670: I/..........(1612): {"f":"103158","p":18,"api":false,"pid":60,"t":114779,"sub":"p10315857a3f8","u":{"id":"103158","name":"xxxxxx","profile_image":"{1}","status":"1"}}
```

Comment: oh!!!! thanks a lot! I've never used Jsoup so I didn't know how it works. Thanks for the document!!!

Comment: @Solorchid no problem just use the above and it should work fine

Answer (score 3):

Well I am bit late to answer this, but have wonderful solution for getting json only string from html response in Android

suppose you have a string in  variable output

```
output= Html.fromHtml(output).toString();
output=output.substring(output.indexOf("{"),output.lastIndexOf("}") + 1);
```

now the output contains only json

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the html with an `XML Parser` and query the value you're looking for using `XPath`.

The `XPath` would be

```
/div/button/@data-invite-details
```

Here's a post that explains how to accomplish that in **`Java/Android`**:

[How to read xml using xpath in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)