# Unable to parse json response with html tags

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am trying to parse json response which have Html tags and getting invalid json exception, I tried this  [Android JSON parsing with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847407/android-json-parsing-with-html-tags)  but unfortunately no success and now I am using **Jsoup.parse()** [reference](https://jsoup.org/) but still getting exception

Here is my json response : 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/HajiV.png

and here is my Kotlin code to parse json using Jsoup

```
         if (response != null) {

                      var jsonObject: JSONObject? = null
                      var dataStr = Jsoup.parse(response.string()).text()
                      if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(dataStr)) {

                          jsonObject = JSONObject(dataStr)
                          var d = jsonObject.getJSONObject("d")
                          var result = d.getJSONObject("result")
                          var dataArr = result.getJSONArray("InformativeContent")

                                     for (position in 0 until dataArr.length()) {
                                         var dataObj: JSONObject = dataArr.getJSONObject(position)
                                         var infoPageObj: JSONObject = dataObj.getJSONObject("InfoPage")

                                         var infoPage = InfoPage(
                                                 infoPageObj.getString("Header"),
                                                 infoPageObj.getString("Heading"),
                                                 infoPageObj.getString("IsHTML"),
                                                 infoPageObj.getString("Message"))
                                         introContentList!!.add(infoPage)
                                     }

                                     /**
                                      * update viewPager UI
                                      */
                                     settingUpPager()
                               }
                         }
```

Please let me know the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var infoPageObj: JSONObject = dataObj.getJSONObject("InfoPage") I think this is wrong. according to your image `InfoPage` is a jsonArray.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing value in wrong order.

In json response "InfoPage" return JSONArray which consist JSON Object of type InfoPage("Header","Heading","isHTML","Message")

```
   for (position in 0 until dataArr.length()) {
                                         var dataObj: JSONObject = dataArr.getJSONObject(position)
                                         var infoPageObj: JSONArray = dataObj.getJSONObject("InfoPage")

for (infoPageposition in 0 until infoPageObj.length()) {

          var infoPageJSONObj: JSONObject = dataArr.getJSONObject(infoPageposition)
                                         var infoPage = InfoPage(
                                                 infoPageJSONObj.getString("Header"),
                                                 infoPageJSONObj.getString("Heading"),
                                                 infoPageJSONObj.getString("IsHTML"),
                                                 infoPageJSONObj.getString("Message"))
                                         introContentList!!.add(infoPage)
                                     }
}
```

Comment: You are also doing same mistake as I did, I was also converting InfoPage into JSONObject which is JSONArray, well I resolved it now.

Comment: @HemendraGangwar Please check, I converted it to jsonarray and fetching values from infoPageJSONObj